# Vue 3 still unauthorized after passing the correct token with Bearer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, token

I have a Vue 3 + node express back-end server + firebase.
On my backend server, the middleware:

```
const getAuthToken = (req, _, next) => {
    if (
        req.headers.authorization &&
        req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer"
    ) {
        req.authToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    } else {
        req.authToken = null;
    }
    next();
};

const checkIfAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    getAuthToken(req, res, async() => {
        try {
            const { authToken } = req;
            const userInfo = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authToken);
            req.authId = userInfo.uid;
            return next();
        } catch (e) {
            return res
                .status(401)
                .send({ error: "You are not authorized to make this request" });
        }
    });
};
```

The /get routes using the middleware

```
router.get('/bearer', checkIfAuthenticated, async function(req, res) {
    res.send('Bearer test');
})
```

App using the following path on port 3000:

```
app.use('/users', userRoute);
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

In front-end i want to make the api call for /users/bearer path but i'm still unaunthorized after passing the token in header:

**In browser front-end client I'm using this path: http://localhost:8080/users/bearer**

```
 async accesPrivateData() {
               const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
      let config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      }; 
      axios.get("http://localhost:3000/users/bearer",config)
            .then(() => {
                    console.log("Am intrat");
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
            });
    }
**I tried to console log the token and it's there!**
```

Index.js Vue router:

```
{
        path: "/users/bearer",
        name: "bearer",
        component: bearer
    }
```

the config after console log:

**console.log(config);**

```
{headers: {…}}
headers: {Authorization: "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVmOTcxMmEwODc.....
```

**EDIT: In checkIfAuthenticated function my  const { authToken } = req; is undefiend**

Comment: did u check the network request. Is the token attached in header there?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the `authorization` headers in different ways, here the 2 most common ways to do it:

with `common` headers:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = <YourToken>;
```

with `interceptor`:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
(config) => {
    let token = <getyourToken>
    if (token) {
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }
    return config;
},

(error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

);

In your code you could try with common by change it to:

```
async accesPrivateData() {
           const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
  
  axios.get("http://localhost:3000/users/bearer")
        .then(() => {
                console.log("Am intrat");
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Still unaunthorized ,i don't think I integrate you're code in a correct way. can you edit how can i properly use ur mechanism?

Comment: I added an example with the `common` headers.

Comment: If youre still getting unauthorized than check your server side code, your bug might be there, start by printing out the headers and see if you receive the token there, in addition to that I would suggest to check your network console on the browser to see the request being made and look for the headers youre sending.

Comment: Yes, on my backend, the  const { authToken } = req; is undefined

Comment: Ok, but are you receiving the token?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227225/discussion-between-andrewz-and-marlon-monroy).